# not able to call correct function?

Tags: erlang

So i have this function that looks for this specific pattern and return ok.

```
id_finder([{id, _, []}|_], _) ->  ok;
```

and i am calling this function in this way:

```
id_finder([{id, whatever, []}], whatever).
```

But i am getting exception error.

> ** exception error: no function clause matching

Why am i getting this error, shouldn't the function return 'ok' in this case?
I have been blindly looking at this function but i dont get why erlang not matching my function with correct call ?

Comment: Yes, the call does match the clause. Are you sure you are actually calling this function (e.g. maybe you didn't recompile after the clause was added, or have a wrong module name)?

Comment: or didn't export it

Comment: Oh thanks for help, the problem was a simple mistake. It was the placement of the function that was incorrect.